# What IP should I use to host my chat server?

Tags: c#, sockets, ip

I made chat server in C# using

```
Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.TCP);
s.Bind(IPAddress.Parse(theIP),thePort);
```

But then I am getting a

> "SocketException was unhandled, The requested address is not valid in
>   its context"

How do I look for the correct IP to use? cmd ipconfig IPv4Address? Because that IP (I believe) is for the internal IP. I want the server IP to be an external IP address that is accessible from outside my network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a static path (sometimes called port forwarding) in your router binding one of your external IP/ports to an internal address and the port needed for your chat server.  You will then reference your internal IP address, on your network, in your code.

Comment: If I dont do it via a router, and use a usb modem, is there a way I can programatically set the server IP and the client application's IP to connect to?

Comment: The IP address that you need for your clients is your external IP address.  Type "whats my ip address" into Google and it will show it at the top, or you can click on any of the links to get your currently assigned IP address.  If you are using a USB modem, you probably have a dynamic IP address assigned to your from your internet service provider which means it changes now and then.  So as a permanent solution this wont work.  But you can use your dynamic IP until it changes.

Comment: You will have to open the ports being used on your windows firewall.